# KnockoutJs SELECT tag is Undefined

Tags: knockout.js, zurb-foundation

I am having an issue where a dropdownlist for part of a model is not binding correctly. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a simplified sample that is binding just fine. But in the complete version, the dropdownlist just says "Undefined".

The model is for an "Employee" and has a set of associated models of "Contacts". The relevant bits look like this:

```
var EmployeeViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.TypesOfContact = ko.observableArray(['Phone Number', 'Website', 'Messaging', 'Address', 'Email Address']);

    self.ContactDetails = ko.observableArray();
    self.ContactDetails().push(new ContactDetail(self.TypesOfContact()[0], 'Home Phone', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''));

    /* snip a bunch of other properties */

};
```

The relevant bits of a ContactDetail look like this:

```
var ContactDetail = function(contactType, addressType, contactField, address1, address2, address3, city, state, postalCode) {
    var self = this;
    self.ContactType = ko.observable(contactType);
    /* snip a bunch of other properties */
};
```

The relevant bit of HTML looks like this:

```
        <div class='row' data-bind="foreach: ContactDetails">
            <div class='small-3 columns '>
                <label>
                    Contact Type
                    <select id="ContactTypeSelect" data-bind='options: $root.TypesOfContact'>
                    </select>

                </label>
            </div>
            <div class='small-9 columns '>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Other properties bind just fine.

If I do this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeViewModel());
```

and then this:

```
var x = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("ContactTypeSelect"));
```

Then x.$root.TypesOfContact() is an Array[6] with all the items I would expect to see. And x.$data.ContactType() is "Phone Number".

However the displayed HTML is a drop down box that says "Undefined" and the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
        <div class="small-3 columns ">
            <label>
                Contact Type
                    <select id="ContactTypeSelect" data-bind="options: $root.TypesOfContact" class="hidden-field" data-id="1375296525390-hq3U3">
                        <option value="Phone Number">Phone Number</option>
                        <option value="Website">Website</option>
                        <option value="Messaging">Messaging</option>
                        <option value="Address">Address</option>
                        <option value="Email Address">Email Address</option>
                        <option value="Phone Number">Phone Number</option>
                    </select><div class="custom dropdown" data-id="1375296525390-hq3U3"><a href="#" class="current">undefined</a><a href="#"
                        class="selector"></a><ul></ul>
                    </div>

            </label>
        </div>
```

If I change my original markup to look like this:

```
<select id="ContactTypeSelect" data-bind='options: $root.TypesOfContact, value:ContactType'></select>
```

There is no difference. Still says Undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using some other plugins/frameworks which may customizes your `select` element?

Comment: Maybe that is it. I am using Zurb Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to nemesv, the answer was to add the "no-custom" class to the select element:

```
<select class="no-custom" id="ContactTypeSelect" data-bind='options: $root.TypesOfContact, value:ContactType'></select>
```

Adding the Zurb Foundation tag to this post.